# How can I display results from a jdbc table on my GUI?

Tags: java, sql, user-interface, jdbc

Hey guys I am trying to take data from a jdbc table I have created and display them on a GUI I created.  It's a program that displays movie names.  My table consists of 7 columns which are:
`MovieID, title,  genre,  year,  mpaaRating,  directors,  company`.  My job is only to display the movieID title year and directors.  The first GUI interface I have created consists of three buttons that each take you to a different interface and they work correctly.  my code for the main interface is:

```
public class MovieGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
 private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;
 private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT= 600;
 private static final int FRAME_X_ORIGIN = 200;
 private static final int FRAME_Y_ORIGIN = 50;
 private static final String dbPrefix = "xxxxx";
 private static final String netID = "xxxxx";
 private static final String hostName = "xxxxx";
 private static final String databaseURL = "jdbc:mysql://"+hostName+"/"+dbPrefix+netID;
 private static final String password = "xxxxx";
 private Connection connection = null;
 private Statement statement = null;
 private ResultSet resultSet = null;
 private JLabel movies[] = new JLabel[20];
 private JLabel promptName;
 private JTextField fieldName;
 private JButton browseMoviesButton, findNameButton, findRatingButton;

 public MovieGUI(){
     setTitle("Menu");
     setResizable(false);
     setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
     setLocation(FRAME_X_ORIGIN, FRAME_Y_ORIGIN);

     Container contentPane = getContentPane();
     contentPane.setLayout(null);
     contentPane.setBackground(Color.red);

     promptName = new JLabel();
     promptName.setText("Movie Rating Services");
     promptName.setBounds(250, 35, 150, 100);
     contentPane.add(promptName);

     browseMoviesButton = new JButton("Browse Movies");
     browseMoviesButton.setBounds(240,120,150,50);
     contentPane.add(browseMoviesButton);
     browseMoviesButton.addActionListener(this);

     findNameButton = new JButton("Find movies given name");
     findNameButton.setBounds(230,220,180, 80);
     contentPane.add(findNameButton);
     findNameButton.addActionListener(this);

     findRatingButton = new JButton("Find movie by rating");
     findRatingButton.setBounds(230,350,180, 80);
     contentPane.add(findRatingButton);
     findRatingButton.addActionListener(this);

     setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }

 public static void main(String args[]){
        MovieGUI obj = new MovieGUI();
        try{
            //connects to database
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("databaseURL =" + databaseURL);
            obj.connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, netID, password);
            System.out.println("Connection Established");
            obj.statement = (Statement) obj.connection.createStatement();
            String sql;
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("command did not go through");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     MovieGUI frameObj = new MovieGUI();
     frameObj.setVisible(true);



     }

 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
     if (event.getSource() instanceof JButton){

            FindName nameObj = new FindName();
            BrowseMovies browseObj = new BrowseMovies();
            FindRating ratingObj = new FindRating();
            JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();
            JRootPane rootPane = clickedButton.getRootPane();
            JFrame frame = (JFrame) rootPane.getParent();
            String buttonText = clickedButton.getText();
            if (buttonText.equals("Browse Movies")){
                 browseObj.setVisible(true);
                 frame.setVisible(false);
                 try {
                    statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
                    String sql;
                    sql = "SELECT movieID, title, year, directors FROM MOVIE";
                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                    int columns = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
                    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
                    while (resultSet.next()) {                          
                        for (int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++){
                            for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {                        
                                message.append(resultSet.getString(j) + "\t\t");    
                        }//end nested for loop
                        message.append("\n");
                        movies[i].setText(message.toString());
                    }//end for loop

                    }//end while loop
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }//end catch

                     for (int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++){
                         movies[i].setBounds(150,60,300,50);
                         browseObj.add(movies[i]);

                     }

             }
            else if(buttonText.equals("Find movies given name")){
                nameObj.setVisible(true);
                frame.setVisible(false);

            }
            else if (buttonText.equals("Find movie by rating")){
                ratingObj.setVisible(true);
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
     }

 }




}
```

When I click the browse movies button, it's supposed to go to the next interface and display the above attributes of the movies in my table, there is 20 of them.

my BrowseMovies interface code is:

```
public class BrowseMovies extends JFrame {
 private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;
 private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT= 600;
 private static final int FRAME_X_ORIGIN = 200;
 private static final int FRAME_Y_ORIGIN = 50;

 private JLabel promptName;
 public BrowseMovies(){
     setTitle("Movie List");
     setResizable(false);
     setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
     setLocation(FRAME_X_ORIGIN, FRAME_Y_ORIGIN);

     Container contentPane = getContentPane();
     contentPane.setLayout(null);
     contentPane.setBackground(Color.blue);

     promptName = new JLabel();
     promptName.setText("Movie Rating Services -- Browse Movies");
     promptName.setBounds(200, 35, 250, 100);
     contentPane.add(promptName);




 }//GUI constructor
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the browseMovies interface is only displaying promptName and nothing else and I am getting a very long error in the console.  The error is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at project5.MovieGUI.actionPerformed(MovieGUI.java:111)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have no idea what's wrong.  I am guessing the problem is somewhere in the try block of the actionPerformed method but I can't seem to find it.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Now, can you put some comment or marker on line 111, which is in the `actionPerformed()` method.

Comment: alright done @EngineerDollery

Comment: the actionPerformed() method @helloworld

Comment: The error says that you have a null pointer exception on line 111. I don't know what line that is, but you do (you should). It's in the MovieGUI class.

Comment: That we know from the stack trace, what exact line in the actionPerformed() method is line 111?

Comment: i copied your code in my editor and i think the line number 111 is for (int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++), is that correct? If yes, yours movies reference is null

Comment: @rahulpasricha -- can't be, can it? movies is initialized at the top of the class (even though it's empty) -- that wouldn't throw a null pointer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: yes, thats correct, Engineer Dollery @user3554599 can you send us the exact java code at line 111 in your MovieGUI class

Comment: also if possible, avoid posting your actual db urls or credentials when you ask a question :)

Comment: movies[i].setText(message.toString()); @rahulpasricha

Comment: thanks for the heads up lol completely forgot about that @rahulpasricha

Comment: is everyone else stumped also??

Comment: you are not initializing your moviews array with the actual object of JLabel, you just created an array of size 20, but you have to initialize each element of an array to a JLabel instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize your array with an actual JLabel object.
The following gives you a null pointer in the first iteration

```
public class TestSwing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JLabel movies[] = new JLabel[20];
        for (int j = 0; j < movies.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Loop Counter : " + j);
            movies[j].setText("Counter : " + j);
        }
    }
}
```

You have to do something similar to this

```
public class TestSwing {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JLabel movies[] = new JLabel[20];
            for (int j = 0; j < movies.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("Loop Counter : " + j);
                movies[j] = new JLabel(); // initialize your JLable
                movies[j].setText("Counter : " + j);
            }
        }
    }
```

NOTE: this is just an extract from your code, i have removed some of your code just to clarify it better

Comment: omg thank you so much I got it now you don't know how much time i've spent on this and the fix was as easy as this!  thanks bro you are a lifesaver